# Toad Query Builder Object Palette is empty

Tags: database, toad

I realize this is a re-ask of [In Toad for Oracle's Schema Browser, my Tables list is empty](https://superuser.com/questions/583115/in-toad-for-oracles-schema-browser-my-tables-list-is-empty), but I don't have the ability to just add a comment yet.

I'm running Toad 12.6 and I've setup a connection to our Oracle data server. When look in the Schema browser I see a large list of tables. But when I open the query builder nothing appears in the Table list.

I tried the answer suggested in the above linked question, but that didn't address the issue, thus my creating this question.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Toad for Oracle's Schema Browser, my Tables list is empty](http://superuser.com/questions/583115/in-toad-for-oracles-schema-browser-my-tables-list-is-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had multiple issues with Toad settings. Object palette blanked out on me, colors off after a power outage etc.

While I don't know the exact way to fix your issue. I suggest the following method when desperate:

1. close Toad
2. Ensure you have a license key jic
3. Scan the AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\\User Files directory for Toad.ini.
4. Back it up
5. Double check that the ini file is backed up
6. Delete the original ini file.
7. Open Toad
8. Observe that the original issue is no longer occurring in this new setup.
9. Close Toad

You now have two ini files - a vanilla ini file inside the user files directory and the old backup.
You are going to be mixing these two so be careful not to corrupt the original ini file!
Move the original and the vanilla ini file (renamed to something else like vanilla.ini) into a new directory for working.
You are going to be creating a new ini file that will contain parts of the other two.

10. Open the two ini files in a text editor (with line numbers unless you are crazy) and copy half of the old ini file with the other half of the vanilla ini file into a thrid file.
11. Save the thrid file as Toad.ini
12. Move the NEW frankensteined ini file into User Files
13. Open toad and observe if the issue is resolved.

If not resolved:
 You now know the setting that is messed up is in the half that you included from the original ini file. Swap the two parts in a new ini.

If resolved 
 You now know which half contains the issue. You can either scan the ini file or continue to break it up in halves until you narrow it down enough to find the exact change.

Best of luck!